# How to color only an accent on a letter?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have this expression in latex :

```
\widetilde{E}^w = (1-w)\widetilde{\mathcal{E}}_1^{\mu, w} + w\widetilde{\mathcal{E}}_2^{\mu, w} - \int {\rm d{\bf r}}\dfrac{\delta E^{{\rm sr}, \mu}_{\rm Hxc}}{\delta n(\bf{r} \rm)}[\widetilde{n}^{w}]\widetilde{n}^{w}({\bf r}) + E^{{\rm sr}, \mu}_{\rm Hxc}[\widetilde{n}^{w}]
```

Which gives a tilde over some letters. I would like to color only this tilde, but not the letter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it :

https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57070/55960

Just change \overline by any accent you want, like \widetilde.